# How do I update my self.tail in a method for deleting a node at a specific position when the position is the last node?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

Method obtained from googling and changed a bit:

```
def removeNodeAtPosition(self, position):
    if self.head == None:
        print("List is empty")
        return
    current = self.head

    if position == 0:               
        self.head = current.next
        current = None
        self.size-=1
        return

    for i in range(position-1):            
        current = current.next
        if current == None:
            break
    if current == None:
        return
    if current.next == None:
        return
    next = current.next.next
    current.next = None
    current.next = next
    if position == self.size:   #two lines here used for updating self.tail
        self.tail = current
    self.size-=1
```

The title mostly says it: my self.tail value isn't changed when I delete the tail of my node with this method. I don't know if I've gone wrong with the placement of my two lines of code or if the code is wrong. I've left the most recent attempt intact. Any help resolving this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Think of removing `current.next` instead of removing `current`. This way if `current.next` is the last element, then `current` would be the new `tail`